# How do you use class based OOP JavaScript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, oop

I've been converting my procedural JS functions into a class and now I'd like to know when to instantiate it.

Here is my class:

```
MyProject = function() {};

MyProject.prototype.myProperty = "10";

MyProject.prototype.myMethod = function (value) {
   // do something

}
```

Here is my HTML page:

```
<script src="javascriptfilesdirectory/MyProject.js"/>

<script>
function initialize() {
   myProject = new MyProject();
}
</script>

<body onload="initialize()" >
```

My question is do I intialize it on page load and create a local variable as shown above or do I initialize it in the JS class file?

Here is my JS file:

```
MyProject = function() {};

MyProject.prototype.myProperty = "10";

MyProject.prototype.myMethod = function (value) {
   // do something

} 

myProject = new MyProject();
```

Also, I'm talking in general and in this case it's a singleton. I only want one copy of it in use.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes, it has prototypes. They allow the same kinds of things, but work in a different way, and trying to force one to work like the other or think of them as the same will probably make you more confused than learning how prototype based inheritance actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want it as a singleton, you can do it easier than that, something like:

```
var myProject = new (function() {
    this.myProperty = "10";
    this.myMethod = function(value) { }
})();
```

Your "class" is only defined long enough to assign it once, since you're never going to instantiate a second copy.

For a non-singleton, I tend to follow the pattern found on the [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) page:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
})();

var greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Comment: So myProject is instantiated when it's first defined? And the methods and properties don't matter if they are not defined on the prototype because it's only going to be called once correct?

Comment: Yep, both statements sound right. If you think there's ever a chance you want to move away from the singleton and potentially define a reusable type, you may be better off just using the prototype pattern, so it would be easier to refactor later.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, I'm talking in general and in this case it's a singleton. I only want one copy of it in use.

In that case, just directly create the object:

```
var myProject = {
    myProperty: "10",
    myMethod: function() { ... }
};
```

When and where you create the object doesn't matter, as long as you have access to it when and where you need it.